# Entity Revisioning Schema Design

Tags: sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005.

In our application, we have an entity with a parent table as well as several child tables. We would like to track revisions made to this entity. After going back and forth, we've narrowed it down to two approaches to choose from.

1. Have one history table for the entity. Before a sproc updates the table, retrieve the entire current state of the entity from the parent table and all child tables. XMLize it and stick it into the history table as the XML data type. Include some columns to query by, as well as a revision number/created date.
2. For each table, create a matching history table with the same columns. Also have a revision number/created date. Before a sproc updates a single table, retrieve the existing state of the record for that one table, and copy it into the history table. So, it's a little bit like SVN. If I want to get an entity at revision Y, I need to get the history record in each table with the maximum revision number that is not greater than Y. An entity might have 50 revision records in one table, but only 3 revision records in a child table, etc. I would probably want to persist the revision counter for the entire entity somewhere.

Both approaches seem to have their headaches, but I still prefer solution #2 to solution #1. This is a database that's already huge, and already suffers from performance issues. Bloating it with XML blobs on every revision (and there will be plenty) seems like a horrible way to go. Creating history tables for everything is a cost I'm willing to eat, as long as there's not a better way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Tedderz

Comment: Start with the end in mind.  Why do you need the history?  Is this just for auditing or do you expect to do something with it.  How will the history be used?  Without knowing these things offering suggestions for 1 vs 2 is personal preference.  #1 has the benefit if designed dynamically can self regulate when table changes occur.  #2 requires recoding unless also dynamic in nature (but changing structure on the fly never floats well with me)  So my point here is.  Not only how will it be used; but what's the nature of changes to parent/entity/child structures?  frequent? static?

Comment: The end user will be able to view the history, and it will also come into play with some business logic as well. It won't be used super heavily, but it will be used here and there. And there will be frequent changes to the structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 2 is almost certainly the way to go, and I do something like this with my history tables, though I use an "events" table as well to correlate the changes with one another instead of using a timestamp.  I guess this is what you mean by a "revision counter".  My "events" table contains a unique ID, a timestamp (of course), the application user responsible for the change, and an "action" designator which represents the application-level action that the user made which caused the change to happen.

Why #2?  Because you can more easily [partition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) the table to archive or roll-off old entries.  Because it's easier to index.  Because it's a WHOLE lot easier to query.  Because it has less overhead than XML and is a lot smaller.

Also, consider using triggers instead of coding a stored procedure to do all of this.  Triggers are almost always to be avoided, but for things like this, they're a fairly lightweight and robust way to perform this kind of thing.

Comment: Ah, that events table is exactly what I need! And I agree on the triggers; we haven't used them as much as we should have in the past. For the events table, do you make one for every single entity? I guess having an events table that tracks events for all entities might get too bloated? I guess it makes sense to split them out both logically and physically.

Comment: No, I make one event per logical transaction, and tie that EventID to each change in each table's history table.  That way, I can correlate which changes happened together.  I use CONTEXT_INFO in SQL Server (or you can use a #temp table) so that the triggers "know" what event ID they're logging.